# Perform a parse a string to a float

Tags: python

In Python, how can I parse a numeric string like `"323.235"` to its corresponding float value, `323.235`, or parse the string `"67"` to an integer, `67`.

I just want to know how to parse a float `str` to a `float`, and (separately) an integer `str` to an `int`.

Comment: Sorry how is 545.2222 to be interpreted as 323.235?

Comment: Use `int()` and `float()` with the string as the argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: This is literally a word for word copy of the marked duplicate, including the 545.2222 "accidentally" posted initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**str to a float**

Just apply this

```
  number= "323.235"
int(float(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
>>> a = "323.235"
>>> float(a)
323.23520000000004
>>> int(float(a))
323
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = "323.235"
fl = float(num)
```

You cannot directly convert a string with decimals to an integer, but you can typecast to float first and then use `int()`, which truncates the float at the decimal point

```
integer = int(fl)
```